# Finding pi value using Leibniz series

Tags: java

I am starting to learn Java and I have a problem with my code.

For sure it has obvious mistakes: it doesn't run. I was asked to find the pi value using Leibniz series and also the number of iterations to reach six significant digit (3.141592).

So far i have this:

```
public class Findingpie2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double pi = 0.0;
        int counter = 1;
        for (int n = 0; n < counter; n++) {
            pi += Math.pow(-1, n) / (2*n + 1);
            counter++;
            if (pi==3.141592) {
                System.out.println("the value of pi is: "+String.format("%6f",4*pi));
                System.out.println("the number of iterations for pi value is "+n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on `"it doesn't run"` -- what does it in fact do? Note that one big problem you have is that your if condition will almost never be true since doubles don't work like that. Because computers are built of digital logical parts that represent data as on or off bits, these types of computers cannot represent floating point numbers with full precision, and so your equality is almost guaranteed to fail. Much better to supply a range.

Comment: Doesnt do anything. So should i assign a range for pi like in between 3 and 4?

Comment: Would between 3 and 4 make sense? Not really -- as that wouldn't be very accurate, would it? Try something a lot closer to 3.141592.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your loop actually runs infinitely. You increment both `counter` and `n` for each iteration, so even when it prints out, it will still continue to run. You may want to add a `break;` at the end of the `if` statement to terminate the loop

Comment: yes you are right, but i am not allowed to use break

Comment: Hmm well then perhaps you could use your range test in place of `n<counter` and print after the loop? Ex. `for(int n=0; pi<3.14159 || pi>3.1416; n++)`. Just spitting ideas to eliminate the infinite loop

Comment: To get alternating sign of the summands there are more efficient methods than `Math.pow(-1, n)`

Answer (score 1):

Using only a tolerance criteria, displaying the result without any rounding:

```
package dummy;

import static java.lang.String.format;
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

/*
 * Finding pi value using Leibniz series
 * 
 * The Leibniz series is converging. To compare two successive values
 * is enough to get the required precision.
 * 
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834854/finding-pi-value-using-leibniz-serie
 * 
 */
public class Findingpie2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        out.println("Pi, no rounding:");
        for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
            double tolerance = Math.pow(0.1, i);
            Entry<Integer, Double> result = calcpi(tolerance);
            String pi = result.getValue().toString().substring(0,  i+1);
            out.println(format("The value of pi is: %s with %." + i + "f tolerance (%d iterations)." , pi, tolerance, result.getKey()));
        }
    }

    private static Entry<Integer, Double> calcpi(double tolerance) {
        int n = 0;
        double pi = 0;
        double bpi = 10 * tolerance;
        double inc = 1;
        while (Math.abs(bpi - pi) > tolerance) {
            bpi = pi;
            pi += inc / (2*n + 1);
            inc = -inc;
            n++;
        }
        return new SimpleImmutableEntry<Integer, Double>(n, 4 * pi);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**: it'll will display:

```
Pi, no rounding:
The value of pi is: 3.1 with 0,01 tolerance (51 iterations).
The value of pi is: 3.14 with 0,001 tolerance (501 iterations).
The value of pi is: 3.141 with 0,0001 tolerance (5001 iterations).
The value of pi is: 3.1416 with 0,00001 tolerance (50001 iterations).
The value of pi is: 3.14159 with 0,000001 tolerance (500001 iterations).
The value of pi is: 3.141592 with 0,0000001 tolerance (5000001 iterations).
The value of pi is: 3.1415926 with 0,00000001 tolerance (50000001 iterations).
The value of pi is: 3.14159265 with 0,000000001 tolerance (499999987 iterations).
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

          double pi = 0.0;
           int MAX_ITERATIONS=1000;
            int n=0;
            while(true) {
                pi += Math.pow(-1, n) / (2*n + 1);
                n++;
                if (n>MAX_ITERATIONS) {
                    System.out.println("the value of pi is: "+String.valueOf(4*pi));
                    System.out.println("the number of iterations for pi value is "+n);
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
```

and the result is: 
the value of pi is: **3.1425916543395442**
the number of iterations for pi value is **1001**

Now, if you want to reach an exact precision, do like this:
Define an acceptable error, in your case, you need need to be 3.141592. Therefore, you need your tolerated error be less than 0.0000001. Change the above code as below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double pi = 0.0;
    double ERROR = 0.0000001;
    int n=0;
    while(true) {
        pi += Math.pow(-1, n) / (2*n + 1);
        n++;
        if (Math.abs(4*pi-Math.PI)<ERROR) {
                    System.out.println("the value of pi is:        "+String.valueOf(4*pi));
                    System.out.println("the number of iterations for pi value is "+n);
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
```

And the result is :

```
the value of pi is: 3.1415919000000936
the number of iterations for pi value is 1326982
```

Comment: The error bound `0.0000001` is smaller than the accuracy of your pi approximation `3.141592`. I suggest, you use `Math.PI` instead of `3.141592`.

Comment: What's that kind of algorithm that uses the searched value to know when to stop searching ;-). With any real algorithm, the end criterion can't use the searched goal.

Comment: You're right, as algorithm suggests, n should be as large as possible, theoretically, tends to infinity. However, the question needs to check when it reaches to a sound precision, say pi. Note that we are estimating an integral with a sum, and we know the exact answer at this specific case, pi.

Comment: Im not familiar eith Math.PI . Your algorithm makes more sense

Comment: @Falahati if you want to check the Leibniz algorithm behavior, i.e. the number of iterations depending on the required precision, see my answer herewith.

Comment: I vote up to your answer. But, note that Leibniz time series is converging and there would not be a pitfall in estimation procedure. You are comparing a value with its previous one to calculate the tolerance. This time this is true, but not all the time. However, your answer is great.